# connecting symbian application to j2me app

Tags: java-me, symbian

is there a way to call java me application out of Symbian's C++ app? Perhaps some link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a Forum Nokia article](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSS000465_-_Launching_MIDlets_programmatically_on_S60_3rd_Edition) about how to launch a Java app from Symbian C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make Symbian code communicate (rather than just launch) with J2ME application code, then one of the simplest ways is to use a local TCP/IP socket. Either make your Symbian or Java code listen on an unused port, then have the other connect to it. Then you can implement some kind of simple protocol to have both sides communicate.